# How to get all the element values of an xml file using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, nodes, traversal

I am trying to traverse through an xml file and view its elements in an html page. My problem is that it only takes the values of the first node and does not go to the next ones. Also I do not know how to take the elements of each node in a more general way like using `name()` function instead of the names of each element or attribute, like in my code, is there a way for that? Because I made some tries but they did not work...

XSL FILE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html><body><h2> Car Model Info </h2>
  <table border="1">
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="elem" select="/*"/>
  </table></body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template mode="elem" match="/*">
  <tr bgcolor="#9acd32" ><th colspan = "12"><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></th></tr>
  <tr><xsl:apply-templates mode="parent" select="/*/*"/></tr>
  <tr><xsl:apply-templates mode="attr" select="/*/*/@*"/></tr>
  <tr><xsl:apply-templates mode="attr_val" select="/*/*/@*"/></tr>
  <tr><xsl:apply-templates mode="child" select="/*/*/*"/></tr>
  <tr><xsl:apply-templates mode="child_val" select="/*/*"/></tr> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template mode="parent" match="/*/*">
  <th colspan="4"><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></th>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template mode="attr" match="/*/*/@*">
  <th><xsl:value-of select="name()"/>(a)</th>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template mode="child" match="/*/*/*">
  <th><xsl:value-of select="name()"/>(c)</th>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template mode="attr_val" match="/*/*/@*">
  <xsl:for-each select = "/*/*">
  <td><xsl:value-of select="//*/@model"/></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="/*/*/@year"/></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="/*/*/@starting_price"/></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="/*/*/@doors"/></td>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template mode="child_val" match="/*/*">
  <xsl:for-each select = "/*/*">
  <td><xsl:value-of select="//type"/></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="//horse_power"/></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="//drivetrain"/></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="//transmission"/></td>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML FILE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="html_xml.xsl"?>
<CarModel>
<Audi model = "TT" year = "2006" starting_price = "33.000$" doors = "2">
    <type>sport</type>
    <horse_power>222hp</horse_power>
    <drivetrain>quattro</drivetrain>
    <transmission>6_Manual</transmission>
</Audi>
<Mercedes model = "W222_S400" year = "2013" starting_price = "63.000$" doors = "4">
    <type>luxury</type>
    <horse_power>302hp</horse_power>
    <drivetrain>front_wheel_drive</drivetrain>
    <transmission>7_Automatic</transmission>
</Mercedes>
<BMW model = "X3_xDrive35i" year = "2010" staring_price = "40.000$" doors = "4">
    <type>crossover_SUV</type>
    <horse_power>302hp</horse_power>
    <drivetrain>quattro</drivetrain>
    <transmission>6_Manual</transmission>
</BMW>
</CarModel>
```

OUTPUT:

```
<html>
<body>
<h2> Car Model Info </h2>
<table border="1">
<tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
<th colspan="12">CarModel</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th colspan="4">Audi</th><th colspan="4">Mercedes</th><th colspan="4">BMW</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>model(a)</th><th>year(a)</th><th>starting_price(a)</th><th>doors(a)</th><th>model(a)</th><th>year(a)</th><th>starting_price(a)</th><th>doors(a)</th><th>model(a)</th><th>year(a)</th><th>staring_price(a)</th><th>doors(a)</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>TT</td><td>2006</td><td>33.000$</td><td>2</td><td>TT</td><td>2006</td><td>33.000$</td><td>2</td><td>TT</td><td>2006</td><td>33.000$</td><td>2</td><td>TT</td><td>2006</td><td>33.000$</td><td>2</td><td>TT</td><td>2006</td><td>33.000$</td><td>2</td><td>TT</td><td>2006</td><td>33.000$</td><td>2</td><td>TT</td><td>2006</td><td>33.000$</td><td>2</td><td>TT</td><td>2006</td><td>33.000$</td><td>2</td><td>TT</td><td>2006</td><td>33.000$</td><td>2</td><td>TT</td><td>2006</td><td>33.000$</td><td>2</td><td>TT</td><td>2006</td><td>33.000$</td><td>2</td><td>TT</td><td>2006</td><td>33.000$</td><td>2</td><td>TT</td><td>2006</td><td>33.000$</td><td>2</td><td>TT</td><td>2006</td><td>33.000$</td><td>2</td><td>TT</td><td>2006</td><td>33.000$</td><td>2</td><td>TT</td><td>2006</td><td>33.000$</td><td>2</td><td>TT</td><td>2006</td><td>33.000$</td><td>2</td><td>TT</td><td>2006</td><td>33.000$</td><td>2</td><td>TT</td><td>2006</td><td>33.000$</td><td>2</td><td>TT</td><td>2006</td><td>33.000$</td><td>2</td><td>TT</td><td>2006</td><td>33.000$</td><td>2</td><td>TT</td><td>2006</td><td>33.000$</td><td>2</td><td>TT</td><td>2006</td><td>33.000$</td><td>2</td><td>TT</td><td>2006</td><td>33.000$</td><td>2</td><td>TT</td><td>2006</td><td>33.000$</td><td>2</td><td>TT</td><td>2006</td><td>33.000$</td><td>2</td><td>TT</td><td>2006</td><td>33.000$</td><td>2</td><td>TT</td><td>2006</td><td>33.000$</td><td>2</td><td>TT</td><td>2006</td><td>33.000$</td><td>2</td><td>TT</td><td>2006</td><td>33.000$</td><td>2</td><td>TT</td><td>2006</td><td>33.000$</td><td>2</td><td>TT</td><td>2006</td><td>33.000$</td><td>2</td><td>TT</td><td>2006</td><td>33.000$</td><td>2</td><td>TT</td><td>2006</td><td>33.000$</td><td>2</td><td>TT</td><td>2006</td><td>33.000$</td><td>2</td><td>TT</td><td>2006</td><td>33.000$</td><td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>type(c)</th><th>horse_power(c)</th><th>drivetrain(c)</th><th>transmission(c)</th><th>type(c)</th><th>horse_power(c)</th><th>drivetrain(c)</th><th>transmission(c)</th><th>type(c)</th><th>horse_power(c)</th><th>drivetrain(c)</th><th>transmission(c)</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>sport</td><td>222hp</td><td>quattro</td><td>6_Manual</td><td>sport</td><td>222hp</td><td>quattro</td><td>6_Manual</td><td>sport</td><td>222hp</td><td>quattro</td><td>6_Manual</td><td>sport</td><td>222hp</td><td>quattro</td><td>6_Manual</td><td>sport</td><td>222hp</td><td>quattro</td><td>6_Manual</td><td>sport</td><td>222hp</td><td>quattro</td><td>6_Manual</td><td>sport</td><td>222hp</td><td>quattro</td><td>6_Manual</td><td>sport</td><td>222hp</td><td>quattro</td><td>6_Manual</td><td>sport</td><td>222hp</td><td>quattro</td><td>6_Manual</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you start your paths inside of templates with `/` or even `//`, that way you always start selecting from the root node respectively document node. So use relative paths simply doing for instance

```
<xsl:template mode="child_val" match="/*/*">
  <td><xsl:value-of select="type"/></td>
```

that way the template outputs the `type` element of the context element of the template. And mixing `for-each` with templates is not necessary for that type of XSLT code, if you want to traverse the document simply write templates and use `apply-templates` to keep up the processing, that way you will reach all nodes and have modular code.

Comment: Thanks! Does this apply for the attributes as well because I wrote this <td><xsl:value-of select="@model"/></td> but it returns null...

Comment: Yes, if the node matched by your template is an element node that has an attribute then using e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="@model"/>` will output the value of the `model` attribute of the element matched by the template. You however also have a template matching attributes with `<xsl:template mode="attr_val" match="/*/*/@*">`, there you would simply use `<xsl:value-of select="."/>` to output the value of the matched attribute. And all that holds as long as you don't have a `for-each` inside the template changing the context node.